# How can I print the large dataGridView/Form on multiple pages?

Tags: c#, winforms

Just using Win Forms in C#. Created Data Grid View and added print button. Here is my code for print button.

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        image = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
        this.dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(new Point(), this.dataGridView1.Size));
        memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        printPDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();

        try
        {
            printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
            image.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            image.Save("d:\\Adnan.bmp");
            p = new PrintDocument();
            p.PrintPage += this.p_PrintPage;

            this.printPDialog.Document = p;
            printPDialog.Show();

        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException ee)
        {

        }

}

    private void p_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        int? line = null;

        // Calculate the number of lines per page.
        linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height /
           printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);   
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromStream(memStream), leftMargin, topMargin);

    }


    private void printPDialog_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.Dispose();
        memStream.Dispose();
    }
```

Problem is my DataGridView has a large list. I have DataGridView inside the FlowLayoutPanel. I tried printing FlowLayoutPanel as well as GridView but in either case the data which is obscure by a vertical scrollbar does not get printed. After spending hours online and trying VB powerpacks I am at loss what to do.

Here is how the data looks in GridView.

[image]

Comment: The problem is the Data Grid View size. When I create Bitmap the datagridview size comes up as a physical size visible on screen which is 1142*633. I am trying now to get the total height of datagridview instead of just physical height and will then try to pass that to bitmap image.

Comment: check out this StackOverFlow posting and follow the suggestions that the individual has highlighted on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530136/how-can-i-print-data-from-a-datagridview-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link where you can try the downloaded code sample 


[How To Print a Data Grid in C# and .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET11212005060838AM/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET.aspx)

Comment: His method has quite a few disadvantages. Most prominent one's are he is printing directly from the DataSet instead of BindingSource. Which means if the data is sorted in Binding Source it will still print the data as it is in the order of DataSet. Second disadvantage is the images you see on the very right side of my grid above is not coming from Database means it is unbounded image and since he is printing DataSet the image will not get printed at all as DataSet doesn't really have it. I just can't believe printing is so difficult in C# but apparently it is. Thanks for the Link though.